# Я написал код но он не работает помогите пожалуйста

Tags: unity3d-android

Я написал код чтобы при нажатии пальцем на экран игрок телепортировался на место нажатия.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class create_city : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] objects;
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 1)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            touchPosition.z = 0f;
            objects[0].transform.position = touchPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.